# How to make an httpRequest from jobs in parse cloud code?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

```
Parse.Cloud.job("syncMetadataWithContentPortal", function(request, status) {
    var apikey ="49eiivmz"; 
    var uid = "t1g4Y2jC6S";
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/functions/getContentMetaData',
        method: 'GET',    
        headers : { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Parse-Application-Id':'appkey',
            'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':'restapikey',  
        },
        body: {
            apiKey : apikey
        }
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {
        Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
        status.message(httpResponse.text);
        console.log(httpResponse.text);
        var contents = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);

        var contentIdCollection = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
            contentIdCollection.push(contents[i].id);
        }
        status.success('Content Synced');
    }, function(httpResponse) {
        // console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
        status.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status)
    });
});
```

So I have a job making httpRequest to call a function `getContentMetaData` which requires API key as a parameter.

1. How do I send parameters using GET method?
2. I got status as :Request failed with response code 405

Please help me how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! How to call this function in android?!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest` to call other cloud functions, instead you should be using `Parse.Cloud.run`

Your problem could also be related to your headers as you appear to be using string literals instead of variable references.

Comment: So I dont have the function 'getContentMetaData' in the current app.That is a cloud function in another app.So that's the reason I have used Parse.Cloud.httpRequest

Comment: You need to confirm exactly what you're doing with the header values then. It looks ok in principle